How does file-based cache in ASP .NET Core Web API work?
For a project I'm working on, I need to retrieve the path of an image from a database. Then use that path to load a locally saved image and load it to convert it to base64. This loading and converting can take a while, therefore I want to use a cache in my API where I can check if the base64 of a certain path is already stored.
So in short I need a cache file to write the path and base64 of an image to in case it isn't in there already.
As far as I know I should use IDistributedCache, but the things that I found so far all look like in-memory cache.

What prevents you from writing the converted b64 to a folder and have a task, that watches the timestamp of the files inside the folder and deletes all files which are older then a configurable duration.

So I think I've found the way to do it in my case. I'm going to create a dictionary which stores the paths to text based files that contain the b64 string. This way it will use the dictionary to quickly see if the path exists with the actual value in a file to save memory.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
